# popToRootViewControllerAnimated does not work with Tab Bar in iOS app

Tags: ios5

Application is structured as follows, this is a storyboard application using segue push

```
Navigation Controller (Root)
View Controller (Login)
    Tab Bar Controller
        Navigation Controller
        View Controller (Options)**
```

**There is a logout button that executes
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

This does nothing, trying to get to the Login view after pressing logout.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Does self.navigationController have a value when you call popToRootViewController?

Add:

```
 NSLog(@" self.navCon is %@", self.navigationController);
```

right before you call pop...

Comment: Yes it does.  Based on my research it seems that the TabBar controller must (should?) be the root controller (even though xcode lets you set it up otherwise).  I have changed my approach so that the login view controller is presented modally when required.